# Extracting xmlsequence from another xmlsequance in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have small problem with xmlsequence. I am codding in PL-SQL (Oracle)

Let's say, my XML looks like this:

```
<Row name="Row1">
<Field name="Filed1">
    <Value1>
    </Value1>
</Field>
<Row name="Row2inRow1">
    <Field name="Filed2">
        <Value1>
        </Value1>
    </Field>
</Row>
<Row name="Row2inRow1">
    <Field name="Filed2">
        <Value1>
        </Value1>
    </Field>
</Row>
```

```
<Row name="Row1">
<Field name="Filed1">
    <Value1>
    </Value1>
</Field>
<Row name="Row2inRow1">
    <Field name="Filed2">
        <Value1>
        </Value1>
    </Field>
</Row>
<Row name="Row2inRow1">
    <Field name="Filed2">
        <Value1>
        </Value1>
    </Field>
</Row>
```

It has 2x same "Row1" which is multiplicated, what's more inside Row1 I have multiplicated "Row2inRow1".

The problem is, I would like to select values from Ro2InRow1 and from Row1, to concat them, the effect should be:

Value1 (from 1st Row1) || Value1 (from 1st Row2inRow1)

Value1(from 1st Row1) || Value1 (from 2nd Row2InRow1)

Value1 (from 2nd Row1) || Value1 (from 3rd Row2inRow1)

Value1(from 2nd Row1) || Value1 (from 4th Row2InRow1)

I've tried to code is somehow, but I can't force my query to work right:

```
declare
xml_data xmldata;
begin
for rec1 in(select extractvalue(value(x),'//Field[@name="Filed1"]/Value1') ValueOfField1,
from table(xmlsequence(extract(xml_data.data,'//Row[@name="Row1"]')))x )
loop
        dbms_output.put_line('1 : '|| ValueOfField1);
        for rec2 in(select extractvalue(value(x),'//Field[@name="Filed2"]/Value1') ValueOfField2,
        from table(xmlsequence(extract(xml_data.data,'//Row[@name="Row2inRow1"]')))k ) --? What here!
    loop
            dbms_output.put_line('1 : '|| ValueOfField2);
    end loop;

end loop;
end;
```

Any ideas ? :(

Comment: Quick advice - XMLSequence is obsolete function. You should use XMLTable instead.

Comment: Your XML is not valid. Not valid at all. :-/